# Mix Blend Mode on Header not taking the background

Tags: html, css

So I am running into a strange problem where my website is ryanstewsart.com I want my header to have blend mode exclusion over a white background. It works with a black background, just with white the header doesn't recognize the background.I tried making the text black but then the blend mode does not work. It works on safari, just not chrome.

```css
body {
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  font-weight: normal;
  webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Sans;
  background-color: white;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  font-family: Sans;
  padding: 5px;
}

.name {
  flex: 1;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.info {
  flex: 1;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 33.1%;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="nav">

    <div class="name"><a href="index.html">Ryan Stewart</a></div>
    <div class="info"><a href="information.html">Information</a></div>

  </div>

</body>
<a href="beansans.html"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCr6b.jpg" alt="Bean Sans" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
    
    <a href="alyx.html"><img src=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRUkH.jpg" alt="alyx" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
    
    <a href="cassette.html"><img src="Images/cass-02%20copy.png" alt="Cassettes" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
    
    <a href="lookat.html"><img src="Images/lookat-this2.gif" alt="Look at This Photograph" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
  
    <a href="popper.html"><img src="Images/pillpopcovermock%202.jpg" alt="Pill Popper" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
   
  
     <a href="canyon.html"><img src="Images/arenamock-Recoverevd.jpg" alt="Canyon Daze" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
  

    
    <a href="tendencies.html"><img src="Images/22.jpg" alt="Tendencies" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;"></a>
```

Comment: actually it's white over white so no blending will happen

Comment: but if I put the text as black no blending happens either

Comment: what kind of blending are you expecting between black and white?

Comment: It to react to the negative of the photo and background

Comment: there is no photo in your code

Comment: https://mouthwash.co like this basically, will update my code

Comment: just added the code with images below

Comment: no, edit your question instead

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We cannot see those images, because they are local to your server. Use a service like placeholder.com to put in images we can actually see.

Comment: which version of chrome are you using ? ... cause , on my side, (latest Chrome/FF - W10) it works fine.

Comment: I am on the latest Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: It works on Firefox as well, just not chrome (Mac)

Comment: the code snippet works because they work over the image, not over just the background. example at www.ryanstewsart.com